# Should I interpolate and use local data model or use server response directly?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am developing an application having angular2 at front-end and laravel at back-end. The front-end communicates with the server using RESTful APIs.

The front-end has a page where an angular component fetches the data from the server and displays it on the screen. Let's assume we have following JSON response

```
{
  "books": [1, 2, 3],
  "is_active": true,
  "user": {
    "first_name": "Munish",
    "last_name": "Kumar",
    "age": 25
  }
}
```

Now, should I interpolate the object properties into HTML directly from server response like so `{{ responseObj.user.first_name }}`    ?

OR

Should I first transform the server response in an angular 2 model class?

```
export class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  age: number

  constructor(fname, lname, age) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.age = age;
  } 
}

const u = responseObj.user;
let user = new User(u.first_name, u.last_name, u.age);
```

and then in HTML `{{ user.firstName }}`

If I don't model the server response in angular class then It might be tedious to change the object properties wherever these properties are being used, if server incorporates a change in JSON response during development.

and sometimes it seems unnecessary to model the response before just displaying it on a page.

is there any best practice or general rule to apply?

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to create a model for your response as an interface. Implement that interface on your custom object as a type.

Assign the response from your subscribers next function to your custom object, and then interpolate the custom object on your component template.

This way you are ensuring that the response always adheres to your object model.